# Which episode has Team Gurren Lagann split out and stand in rows infront of the Mecha?

Tags: gurren-lagann

I am talking about this particular shot:
[image]

Which episode does this scene come from?

Comment: https://trace.moe/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FK30wJ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the last episode of the series. See [here](https://gurrenlagann.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_27) for a recap of this episode (obviously with spoilers!), with the depicted scene described such:

> Nia smiles and thirteen drills crash down in front of Gurren Lagann in two columns containing Yoko, Viral, Gimmy, ...